# StackList and StackArrays python

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, stack

so i am a bit confused as to how to attack the StackList and Node portion of this homework.. I barely have any programming experience, and after a full day of struggling I finally understood StackArray. But I also need to understand how I can implement the same functions into a LinkedList... Here are the instructions in case I cant be clear ..

The goal of this project is to implement the Stack Abstract Data Type using the built in List construct in
Python and the Stack ADT using the simple linked data structure covered in class.
As discussed in class you are to allocate a list of size stack_capacity and use this to store the items in the
stack. Since Lists in python expand when more storage is needed you will have to provide a mechanism to
prevent the list inside your stack from growing. This really prevents the stack from growing if the user only
accesses it through the given interface but that is fine for the purposes of this exercise. (This prevents the stack
from using more space that a user might want. Think of this as a requirement for an application on a small
device than has very limited storage.) In the case when a user attempts to push an item on to a full stack, your
push function (method) should raise an IndexError. Similarly if a user tries to pop an empty, your pop function
(method) should raise an IndexError. 
tly

```
class StackArray:
"""Implements an efficient last-in first-out Abstract Data Type using a Python List"""

def __init__(self, capacity):
    """Creates and empty stack with a capacity"""
    self.capacity = capacity        # this is example for list implementation
    self.items = [None]*capacity        # this is example for list implementation
    self.num_items = 0          # this is example for list implementation

def is_empty(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is empty and false otherwise"""

def is_full(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is full and false otherwise"""

def push(self, item):

def pop(self):

def peek(self):

def size(self):
   """Returns the number of elements currently in the stack, not the capacity"""
```

Submit to two files:

• stacks.py containing a list based implementation of stack and a linked implementation of stack. The
classes must be called: StackArray and StackLinked . Both implementations should follow the above
specification and be thoroughly tested.

• test_stacks.py contains your set of tests to ensure you classes work correctly

So far this is what I have come up with

```
class StackArray:
"""Implements an efficient last-in first-out Abstract Data Type using a Python List"""

def __init__(self, capacity):
    """Creates and empty stack with a capacity"""
    self.capacity = capacity        # this is example for list implementation
    self.items = [None]*capacity        # this is example for list implementation
    self.num_items = 0          # this is example for list implementation

def is_empty(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is empty and false otherwise"""
    return self.num_items == 0


def is_full(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is full and false otherwise"""
    return self.num_items == self.capacity

def push(self, item):
    self.num_items += 1
    self.items[self.num_items - 1] = item


def pop(self):
   return self.items.pop(0)


def peek(self):
    return self.items[0]


def size(self):
   """Returns the number of elements currently in the stack, not the capacity"""
   return self.num_items
```

class Node:
    # ? ? 
    # nodes have 2 parts to them data and pointer. Pointer always points to the data of previous

class StackLinkList:

```
def __init__(self, capacity):
    """Creates and empty stack with a capacity"""
    self.capacity = capacity  # this is example for list implementation
    self.items = [None] * capacity  # this is example for list implementation
    self.num_items = 0  # this is example for list implementation

def is_empty(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is empty and false otherwise"""


def is_full(self):
    """Returns true if the stack self is full and false otherwise"""


def push(self, item):



def pop(self):



def peek(self):



def size(self):
   """Returns the number of elements currently in the stack, not the capacity"""
```

And these are my testcases

```
import unittest
```

from stacks import *

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):

```
# testing an empty Array

def test_if_empty(self):
    s1 = StackArray(3)  #[none,none,none]
    self.assertTrue(s1.is_empty())  # Should be True

def test_if_not_empty(self):
    s1 = StackArray(4)  #[none,none,none,none]
    s1.push(2)     #[2,none,none,none]
    s1.push(3)      #[2,3,none,none]
    s1.push(4)      #[2,3,4,none]
    self.assertFalse(s1.is_empty())  # this is saying that the statement that the string is empty is false

def test_if_full(self):
    s1 = StackArray(3)      #[none,none,none]
    s1.push(5)  #[5,none,none]
    s1.push(4)  #[5,4,none]
    s1.push(3)  #[5,4,3]
    self.assertTrue(s1.is_full()) #this is checking to see if its true that the stack is full

def test_if_not_full(self):
    s1 = StackArray(2)  # [none,none]
    s1.push(2)          # [2,none]
    self.assertFalse(s1.is_full())  # it is false that the stack is full

def test_IfWeCanPush(self):
    s1 = StackArray(3)      #[none,none,none]
    s1.push(2)  #[2,none]
    s1.push(3)  #[2,3]
    self.assertFalse(s1.is_full())  # it is false that the stack is full

def test_IfWeCantPush(self):
    s1 = StackArray(3)  #[none,none,none]
    s1.push(2)      #[2,none,none]
    s1.push(3)      #[2,3,none]
    s1.push(3)      #[2,3,3]
    self.assertTrue(s1.is_full())

def test_ifWeCanPop(self):
    s1 = StackArray(3)  #[none,none,none]
    s1.push(3)  #[3,none,none]
    s1.push(3)  #[3,3,none]
    s1.push(5)  #[3,3,5]
    # This gives us an array [3,3,5]
    s1.pop()    # now we have [3,5]
    s1.pop()    # now we have [5]
    self.assertFalse(s1.is_empty())
    self.assertEqual(s1.pop(),5)

def test_ifWeCantPop(self):
    s1 = StackArray(2)  # this gives us [none,none]
    self.assertFalse(s1.pop())

def test_ifWeCanPeek(self):
    s1 = StackArray(4)
    s1.push(4)
    s1.push(3)
    s1.push(5)
    s1.push(54)
    self.assertEqual(s1.peek(),4) #this statement says that if we peek at the top of the stack it should be 4

def test_ifWeCanSeeTheSize(self):
    s1 = StackArray(5)
    s1.push(3)
    self.assertEqual(s1.size(),1)  # this statement checks that the size or number of items in the
                                    # stack is 1 ... [ 3,none,none,none,none] only has one item which is 3
```

if (**name** == '**main**'):

```
unittest.main()
```

Comment: What's your question? You've just dumped your code and assignment and said you're confused.

Comment: im confused as to how to construct the node and stackList according to her instructions.. i understand that a node is made of 2 parts ( a data portion and a pointer portion) but i dont understand how to create the syntax for that. I would like to find some easy examples so that i can catch some speed and figure it out, but everything seems to be very cryptic online.  Also, I was told by my teacher that python has no constructors, yet I saw on my search results that the node had getters and setters ... How or where could I go to gain some knowledge on this ?